# How to fix i18n delay on my ssr Angular 15 app?

Tags: angular, internationalization, ngx-translate

I have an Angular 15 app and I set `internationalization i18n` and it works good. My app is not big and have only 2 pages. Now when I added SSR to my app I get some problems with translation but it can see only in production (on localhost I can't observe this problem), so when my page is loading where I use the translation I get first of all the path like `translation.title` and after 2-3 seconds I get the text.[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmYuI.png) [example after page load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDEav.png)

I created a translate interceptor

```
@Injectable()
export class TranslateInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  private readonly DEFAULT_PORT = 4000;
  // @ts-ignore
  private readonly PORT = process.env.PORT || this.DEFAULT_PORT;

  constructor(@Inject(REQUEST) private request: express.Request) {
  }

  getBaseUrl(req: express.Request) {
    const { protocol, hostname } = req;
    return this.PORT ?
      `${protocol}://${hostname}:${this.PORT}` :
      `${protocol}://${hostname}`;
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    if (request.url.startsWith('./assets')) {
      const baseUrl = this.getBaseUrl(this.request);
      request = request.clone({
        withCredentials: true,
        url: `${baseUrl}/${request.url.replace('./assets', 'assets')}`,
      });
    }
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

And in app module i add:

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient],
      },
    }),
```

And use it in app component like:

```
  constructor(readonly appService: AppService, private router: Router, private translate: TranslateService) {
    this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
    this.translate.use('en');
  }
```